# What is the difference between <a target="_top"/> and window.open("", "_top") with sandboxed iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe in which I have one link and one button. The domains of the parent window and iframe are different.

My use case is, on clicking of both of these widgets, I need to navigate the user to different url on the parent window.

My anchor tag looks like this -

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_top">Click Me!</a>
```

On my button click I am doing window.open like this -

```
window.open("http://example.com", "_top");
```

My anchor tag click works fine and changes the URL of the parent window.

But the button click doesn't work and I get this below error:

> `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin '...' from frame with URL '...'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.`

My **questions** are

- Shouldn't the behaviour be same for both?
- If we set "sandbox" attribute on the iframe and do not provide "allow-top-navigation" and "allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" flags then how is anchor tag's `href` is able to open the link on the parent window?
- Also, is there any way to trigger navigation on the parent window on a button click even though `allow-top-navigation` flag is not set?

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue, not just one-line snippets that make it impossible for us to tell the exact context. Depending on how exactly you implemented this, and whether there might be any asyncronous stuff going on, the `-by-user-activation` part could make a difference here.

Comment: `<a href="..." target="_top"`  is not scripted and hence allowed more than window.open

Comment: Hey @Arpitha Chandrashekara is that happen in FF or IE for same.

Comment: @ChintanKotadiya I could reproduce this in both Chrom and FF.